# Cannot Serialize exception in SOAP Parsing in android

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I am trying to do SOAP parse, but getting an error. On catching exception in line `transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`,  got Exception: `Cannot Serialize`

Code:

```
private double getFahrenheit(double celsius) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    double farenheit = 0.0;
    SoapObject request =new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo(); 
    SoapPrimitive primitive;

    info.setName("Celsius");
    info.setValue(celsius);
    info.setType(double.class);

    request.addProperty(info);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
    new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        primitive = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse(); 
        farenheit = Double.parseDouble(primitive.toString());
        return farenheit;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130): Process: com.example.demosoapparsing1, PID: 2130

01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 55.0
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:629)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:613)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:582)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:566)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:623)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:547)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:192)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:74)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:58)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at com.example.demosoapparsing1.MainActivity.getFahrenheit(MainActivity.java:101)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at com.example.demosoapparsing1.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:77)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at com.example.demosoapparsing1.MainActivity$CalculateAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:157)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at com.example.demosoapparsing1.MainActivity$CalculateAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-15 14:53:29.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2130):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Answer (score 0):

For info.setType(double.class); You should register marshaller.
See fe. this link [How to serialize double value using kSOAP in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498645/how-to-serialize-double-value-using-ksoap-in-android)